# How would I modify a Google Script that applies conditional formatting to accept a list of cells rather than a range

Tags: google-apps-script

I found this wonderful script here: [https://stackoverflow.com/a/65773800/12740660](https://www.stackoverflow.com/) that will apply conditional formats to a Google Sheet via a script when provided with a range.

Here is the script that was originally written by Iamblichus

```
function applyConditionalFormat() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheets = ss.getSheets(); // Remove if not all sheets
  //var sheetNames = ['Screening','Quality', ...]; // Uncomment if not all sheets
  //var sheets = sheetNames.map(sheetName => ss.getSheetByName(sheetName)); // Uncomment if not all sheets
  sheets.forEach(sheet => {
    //sheet.clearConditionalFormatRules(); // Uncomment if want to remove previous rules
    var rules = [];
    rules.push(createRule(sheet, "A1:NH", "=A$1=TODAY()", "#b7e1cd"));
    rules.push(createRule(sheet, "C2:NH", "=$B2>=10", "#cc0000"));
    rules.push(createRule(sheet, "C2:NH", "=$B2>=8", "#ea9999"));
    rules.push(createRule(sheet, "C2:NH", "=$B2>=5", "#f6b26b"));
    rules.push(createRule(sheet, "C2:NH", "=$B2>=2", "#ffe599"));
    sheet.setConditionalFormatRules(rules);
  });
}

function createRule(sheet, rangeNotation, formula, color) {
  var range = sheet.getRange(rangeNotation);
  var rule = SpreadsheetApp.newConditionalFormatRule()
    .whenFormulaSatisfied(formula)
    .setBackground(color)
    .setRanges([range])
    .build();
  return rule;
}
```

If I add in a list of cells such as :
`rules.push(createRule(sheet, "C2, C3, C4, H1, H2, H3, N5", "=$B2>=10", "#cc0000"));`

I get an error and it fails. How would I go about modifying the script so that it would accept a list of cells rather than range.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The argument of `setRanges(ranges)` of Class ConditionalFormatRuleBuilder is `Range[]`. So when you want to use `"C2, C3, C4, H1, H2, H3, N5"` as the ranges, as a sample modification, how about the following modification?

#### Modified script:

```js
function applyConditionalFormat() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
  var rule = createRule(sheet, "C2, C3, C4, H1, H2, H3, N5", "=$B2>=10", "#cc0000");
  sheet.setConditionalFormatRules([rule]);
}

function createRule(sheet, rangeNotation, formula, color) {
  var ranges = sheet.getRangeList(rangeNotation.split(",").map(e => e.trim())).getRanges();
  var rule = SpreadsheetApp.newConditionalFormatRule()
    .whenFormulaSatisfied(formula)
    .setBackground(color)
    .setRanges(ranges)
    .build();
  return rule;
}
```

- In this modification, the value of `rangeNotation` given by `createRule(sheet, "C2, C3, C4, H1, H2, H3, N5", "=$B2>=10", "#cc0000")` is converted to the value of `Range[]`. And, the value is used with `setRanges(ranges)`.

#### References:

- [map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)
- [setRanges(ranges) of Class ConditionalFormatRuleBuilder](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/conditional-format-rule-builder#setrangesranges)

Answer (score 0):

#### Building a DataValidaton from a RangeList

```
function dataValidatoinFromAListOfRanges() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();    
  const sh = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet0");
  const rgl = sh.getActiveRangeList();
  //const rgl = sh.getRangeList("A1","C42","L24","Z1");//alternative way to create rangelist
  let a = rgl.getRanges().map(r => r.getValue());
 let dv = SpreadsheetApp.newDataValidation()
 .requireValueInList(a)
 .build();
 sh.getRange(2,20,10).setDataValidation(dv);
}
```

I used a select rangelist

[image]